# Unable to find SpecRun.exe when using SpecFlow 1.9 and SpecRun 1.1

Tags: bdd, specflow

Just downloaded the latest SpecFlow 1.9 from NuGet into the BookStore demo.

The scenarios run fine - everything passes.

When I install SpecRun 1.1 from NuGet and run the scenarios, SpecFlow gives me a dialog box that states: "Unable to find SpecRun.exe."

I have removed MSTest runner from app.config.

I have verified that SpecRun.exe is in:
\BookShop\packages\SpecRun.Runner.1.1.0\tools

It compiles fine, the site still runs fine - just not SpecFlow using SpecRun.

Am i missing a config step?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to upgrade both the NuGet-package **and** the VS IDE integration; http://www.specflow.org/specflownew/WhatsNew19.html.

Worked for me at least :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with the removal of MSTest. I had the same error ("Unable to find SpecRun.exe"), and in my case it was because the Test runner tool in my project settings was not set to MSTest.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar problem.
Try to install SpecFlow 1.9.2 extension via Tools->Extension Manager...